# Ruby On Rails - Make text green if there is >

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am learning rails.
I am building image-board as my first project.

Basically I need to change text color if there is `>` in text

[image: Here is picture how it should look like]

Comment: Your question doesn't demonstrate any research or specifics. I would recommend looking into JQuery and editing your question if you have any issues.

Comment: This would be better done with jQuery and ripping through a subsection of the DOM tree.

Comment: It seems to be a bit more complex. There's some green text starting with `>` and red text starting with `>>` which is also underlined (a hyperlink?). Could you show the corresponding code, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 # in your CSS
 .green {
  color: green;
 }


# in your view
<div class="<%= 'green' if text.include?('>') %>"><%= text %></div>
```

Comment: This helped me but when I go to the next row from > text stayes green

Comment: Can you show how the input text looks like? How you render the view?

Is the full text in one string? Then you need to split it up.

Comment: <h2 id="post-content-index" class="<%= 'green' if comment.body.include?('>') %>" style="font-size: 15px;" ><%= simple_format(comment.body).gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %></h2>

Comment: I though about making span inside <h2> if there is > but I dont know how to do it

Comment: please update your question with this information. There is no formatting in comments. And this will help others.